# Swift: How to check if a range is valid for a given string

Tags: swift, xcode

I have written a swift function that takes a String and a Range as its parameters.  How can I check that the range is valid for the string?

Edit: Nonsensical Example

```
func foo(text: String, range: Range<String.Index>) ->String? {
  // what can I do here to ensure valid range
  guard *is valid range for text* else {
    return nil
  }
  return text[range]
}

var str = "Hello, world"
let range = str.rangeOfString("world")
let str2 = "short"
let text = foo(str2, range: range!)
```

Comment: Please show the code you have written.

Comment: Just check if range is not equal to nil before calling your method or use if let to safely get your range.

Comment: I agree with @LeoDabus. If `range` is not `nil`, it is valid for `str`. To put it another way, if "world" were not present, `range` would be `nil`. What else do you want to know?

Comment: Every string has its own characteristics so it doesn't work like that.

Comment: I understand that Leo, but if someone was to do to foo what I did then I would like to perform some validation in foo so that the app doesn't crash

Comment: Do another search (rangeOfString) on the new string

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Swift 3, this is easy: just get the string's character range and call `contains` to see if it contains your arbitrary range.

**Edit**: In Swift 4, a range no longer "contains" a range. A Swift 4.2 solution might look like this:

```swift
let string = // some string
let range = // some range of String.Index
let ok = range.clamped(to: string.startIndex..<string.endIndex) == range
```

If `ok` is true, it is safe to apply `range` to `string`.

Comment: I have resolved issue using the concepts you described (see below).  Thank you

Comment: The Swift 4 edit is wrong, a range doesn't contain its `upperBound`. You could do `string.startIndex <= range.lowerBound && string.endIndex >= range.upperBound`.

Comment: @Pascal It was never a very good question. In Swift 4 it is unclear to me how you could possibly even _form_ an invalid range in the first place.

Comment: @Pascal provided an alternative one-liner that I think is a lot more pleasant.

Answer (score 6):

Swift 5

```
extension String {
    func hasRange(_ range: NSRange) -> Bool {
        return Range(range, in: self) != nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I was not able to test Matt's solution as I am using swift 2.2. However, using his idea I came up with ...

```
func foo(text: String, range: Range<String.Index>) -> String? {
  let r = text.startIndex..<text.endIndex
  if r.contains(range.startIndex) && r.contains(range.endIndex) {
    return text[range]
  } else {
    return nil
  }
}
```

If the start and end indices are ok then so must be the entire range.